# Java Spring Security not authenticating in safari browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, safari

This is my spring-security.xml code.

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/signin" authentication-failure-url="/signin?error"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="AppSuccessAuthenticationHandler" />
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/signin?logout" />
        <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/signin">  
        </sec:session-management>       
    </sec:http>
```

what is wrong here.. I can successfully signin through all other browsers.

Comment: any help would be nice..

Comment: are your cookies retained when you log in?

Comment: String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

this is "anonymousUser" from safari.. I don't know how.. any idea?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?